# Is it right to not change “tomorrow“ into “the next day” when it is indirect speech?

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

Is that sentence right or it is necessary to change “tomorrow”?

> He said that he would travel ***tomorrow***.
>   He said that he would travel ***the next day*.**

Comment: Is there a reason you would think it might be necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just like: "He left two days ago." He said he left two days before.